# Find all sets of positive integers $a, b, c$ satisfying the three congruences :

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$a ≡ b \pmod c$ , $b ≡ c \pmod a , c ≡ a \pmod b$ .

What I tried :
I wrote $a ≡ b \pmod c$ as $by + c = a$ , $b ≡ c \pmod a$ as $cz + a = b $, $c ≡ a \pmod b$ as $ax + b = c$ .
Then from these equations I got $ax + by + cz = 0$ ,I don't know what to do further .

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, assume $a\geqslant b \geqslant c$.

Because $a|b-c, a> b-c\geqslant 0$, so $b=c$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your help but i managed to solve it by a bit different approach